# Why does it seem like the strings are not equal?

Tags: c, string, fgets, strcmp

```
int main()
{        
    int n = 100;    
    char a[n];    
    char b[ ]="house";

    fgets(a,n-1,stdin); // type "house"

    if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)
        printf("The strings are equal.\n");
    else
        printf("The strings are not equal.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what's strlen(a) and strlen(b)?

Comment: Because `fgets()` includes the newline at the end of the input and the string you're comparing with does not.

Comment: `// more like type "house<ENTER>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason why this

```
if (strcmp(a,b) == 0) { }
```

is not true because `fgets()` stores the `\n` at the end of buffer. So here array `a` looks like `house` and array `b` looks like `house\n`(If `ENTER` key was pressed after entering input char's) and `strcmp(a,b)` doesn't return `0`.
From the manual page of `fgets()`

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>          and stores them into the buffer pointed to by  s.   Reading  stops
>          after  an  EOF  or  a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored
>          into the buffer.**  A terminating null byte ('\0') is  stored  after
>          the last character in the buffer.

One way is to use `strcspn()` which removes the trailing `\n`. For e.g

```
fgets(a,n,stdin);
a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = 0;
```

Now compare the char array like

```
if (strcmp(a,b) == 0) {
        printf("The strings are equal.\n");
}
else {
        printf("The strings are not equal.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, this is what strcmp is comparing

```
strcmp("house\n", "house")
```

Which is false.

Here is a solution you could add to fix your code to the way (I assume) you expect it to work.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 100;
    char a[n];
    char b[] = "house";
    fgets(a, n-1, stdin);
    a[strlen(a) - 1] ='\0';  //you may want to add length checking to prevent errors if user input is null
    if (strcmp(a, b) == 0)
        printf("The strings are eq\n");
    else
        printf("Not eq\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[strlen(a) - 1] ='\0';` --> `a[strcspn(a, "\n")] ='\0';` is a nice one line alternative without the error concerns.

Comment: Minor 1  not needed.  Recommend `fgets(a, n, stdin);`